# How do i find out if an item exists in a Hashset of Arrays of size 2 when the items are stored in Arr[0]?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, testing, hashset

I am trying to create a Locker class and a Long Term Storage class for homework at uni. 
Both of them should be able to store an Item object that was already made by our teachers that has a volume and a type.
(while each Locker has a limited amount of storage units and the long term storage has a set amount of 1000 units.)
I am trying to decide how to implement the storage in the best way. 
I thought about just creating an Array, because i know generally speaking a 1000 items tops isn't much, but i want to write the best and most efficient code i can, and there is no importance for their order.
We just learned about HashSets and so i thought about maybe creating a HashSet, which makes the runtime of my program WAY BETTER.
The issue is that i need to keep count of the amount of items stored of each kind and sets do not allow duplicate.
And so i thought about maybe creating a HashSet of Arrays with length of 2 that keep track of a type of item and it's amount in the storage.

I am not really sure what is the best way to implement such storage and maybe im going with the absolute wrong way. It just seems to me like simple Arrays are not very efficient when i want to find a specific kind of item out of a 1000. (in case a 1000 different items of a different type and volume of 1 are stored in the long term storage).

An extra question: in this exercise im supposed to work with the TDD method (Test Driven Development) and im not sure how to implement the testing code properly. help would be appreciated. (Supposed to work with JUnit and Asserts).

An example of the start of my code:

```
import oop.ex3.spaceship.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class Locker {

    private static final int TOO_MANY_ITEMS = -1;
    private static final int WORKED_WELL = 0;
    private static final int MOVED_TO_LONG_TERM = 1;

    private final int capacity;
    private int currentLoad;
    private HashSet<Item> itemsStored;

    public Locker(int capacity){
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.currentLoad = 0;
        itemsStored = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public int addItem(Item item, int n){
        if (currentLoad + n*item.getVolume() < capacity){


        }
        else{
            return this.TOO_MANY_ITEMS;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

Consider using a HashMap instead of a HashSet. Specifically, consider

`HashMap<KeyType, Object[]>`, or, even better,

`HashMap<KeyType, ItemWrapper>`

where KeyType is a String, Integer, or some other type of a unique identifier in your Item class, and ItemWrapper is a simple class for storing related data.

### HashMap might be more appropriate for this than HashSet

You say you don't want to use arrays because you want fast retrieval using an identifier other than the order in which it was added. You also want to "map" your items to a count of the quantity. HashMap would allow you to associate a key with a value for quick look-up.

We'll start with an overly-simple implementation, then make it better. I'll also show how you could instead use arrays of size 2 like you ask, even though that's not the best approach.

### Basic implementation that we'll improve on

In an overly simple implementation, your key could be your Item and your value could be the quantity. For example,

```
        HashMap<Item, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<Item, Integer>(1400);

        public int addItem(Item item, int n) {
            //...
            int currentCount = myHashMap.getOrDefault(item, 0);
            myHashMap.put(item, n + currentCount);
            //...
        }

        public int quantityOf(Item item) {
            return myHashMap.getOrDefault(item, 0);
        }

        public boolean isInLocker(Item item) {
            return myHashMap.containsKey(item);
            //or return this.quantityOf(item) > 0;
        }
```

(Note that this code relies on [autoboxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), but can be written without it if you prefer. Also, you can adjust the hashmap's initial capacity. With an initial capacity of 1400 and load factor of .75, it will resize once there are about 1050 items in the HashMap.)

The trouble with that is that you would then need to have the Item object already in order to look up that item, which might not be practical in most situations. (Or, at least, you would need something with the same result from `hashCode()` and that returned true for `equals()`). You could add `@Overrides` for `hashCode()` and `equals()` in the Item class if appropriate. However, what if the Item class is provided for you, you're not allowed to change it (or don't want to), and the `hashCodes()` and `equals()` don't meet your needs for quick look-up? In that case, you would have to have a different key, like an item ID or a unique descriptor (a string would work if all "pencil" items were treated the same in your program, for example).

### More Robust Approach

In order to make your dream of fast retrieval work with a HashMap, you need a unique way of identifying Item objects--we'll use this as the key. For the example code below, I assume the identifier is a String. You also need a way to associate the Item with the quantity.

Instead of using an Object[], I'd recommend wrapping the Item in a new, simple class that keeps track of both the item and its quantity. For example:

```
class ItemWrapper {
    Item item;
    int quantity;
}
```

(I kept the example simple, but you can make members private, add getters/setters, etc, as appropriate.)

That way, your code is more readable and requires fewer casts. Then, you'd use it with code something like this:

```
        HashMap<String, ItemWrapper> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, ItemWrapper>(1400);

        public int addItem(Item item, int n) {
            //...
            ItemWrapper wrappedItem = myHashMap.get(item.uniqueID);
            if (wrappedItem == null) {
                wrappedItem = new ItemWrapper(item, n);
            }
            else {
                wrappedItem.quantity += n;
            }
            myHashMap.put(item.uniqueID, wrappedItem);
            //...
        }

        public int quantityOf(String itemID) {
            ItemWrapper wrappedItem = myHashMap.get(itemID);
            return wrappedItem == null ? 0 : wrappedItem.quantity;
        }

        public boolean isInLocker(String itemID) {
            return myHashMap.containsKey(itemID);
            //or return this.quantityOf(itemID) > 0;
        }
```

### Direct answer to your question using Arrays (not the best approach)

In your question, you asked about an array of size 2. The above approach is my recommendation, but if you *must* use arrays, you could do something like the following code:

```
        HashMap<Item, Object[]> myHashMap = new HashMap<Item, Object[]>(1400);

        public int addItem(Item item, int n) {
            //...
            Object[] itemBundle = myHashMap.get(item.uniqueID);
            if (itemBundle == null) {
                itemBundle = new Object[2];
                itemBundle[0] = item;
                itemBundle[1] = new Integer(n);
            }
            else {
                itemBundle[2] = new Integer((Integer)itemBundle[2] + n);
            }
            myHashMap.put(item.uniqueID, itemBundle);
            //...
        }

        public int quantityOf(String itemID) {
            return myHashMap.getOrDefault(itemID, 0);
        }

        public boolean isInLocker(String itemID) {
            return myHashMap.containsKey(itemID);
            //or return this.quantityOf(itemID) > 0;
        }
```

### TDD

Your "extra question" about Test-Driven Development is probably best researched as a separate question. And are you asking about how to conceptually approach TDD, or how to actually write the code for tests? Either way, you can likely find great answers by searching StackOverflow's existing content.

Comment: Thank you **very much** ! 
I asked question in stack sites before but never got such a well all rounded answer :)

Comment: Does a Type field in the Items that is a string suffice as a uniqueID?

Comment: In my examples, uniqueID is used as a key. If Item's type variable refers to what type of item it is, then yes, it would probably make sense to use type as the key. When choosing a key, just remember this: for any Item objects x and y, if the keys are the same, that means you want to treat them as though they're the same Item. I'm glad the answer was helpful to you! :)

Comment: Sorry for the barrage of questions, but i have another one. Why would you use an ItemWrapper if within the Item itself there is a type as a key?
Couldn't i use the Item type as the key and the count as the value?

Comment: There's a paragraph in my answer that starts with  "The trouble with that is..." Does that give you an answer, or did you have a follow-up?

Comment: @ash I just realized you asked about item.type, not item. Your question makes sense now. You certainly could do that, but then you'd need a separate collection (List, HashMap, Array, etc) of the Item objects so that you could access their getVolume() methods and other methods. It's usually a good idea to avoid storing similar data in separate collections, because if you change one collection you need to remember to change the other.

Comment: Maybe im a bit dense here but i don't really understand what the problem is. I thought about not actually saving the Items and only saving representations of them, and then using a String of their value as the key. 
Did you mean that if i save the actual items, the hashcode wont conclude in the same result for two of the same type?

Comment: Thanks, just saw your answer :)